# Recommended strategy to use Value Objects for ID's in Spring Data

Tags: sql, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Using Value Objects can have a lot of advantages, especially when it comes to the type strictness of it. Using a PersonKey to use a Person (where the PersonKey really is a wrapped Long) is a lot safer than just using a Long or String as-is. I was wondering what the recommended strategy to deal with this in Spring Data is, however. Setting up the Repository is of course a matter of for example using

```
public interface PersonRepository CrudRepository<Person, PersonKey> {
}
```

but I was wondering what the best way to make the PersonKey class would be, having it map easily. Is there a better option than using an EmbeddedKey?

Comment: Did you take a look at "user types"? https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two annotations to do it : `IdClass` or `EmbeddedId`. I would recommend to use `EmbeddedId` because you don't have to repeat all of your attributes of your id class into your entity class.

Let's say you use `EmbeddedId`. It would looks like this :

```
 @Embeddable 
 public class PersonKey {

    private Long id;
 }

 @Entity
 public class Person {

   @EmbeddedId
   private PersonKey personKey;
 }
```

And you will access to your id like this :
`select p.personKey.id from Person p`

But with `IdClass`, your Person class would look like this :

```
 @Entity
 @IdClass(Person.key)
 public class Person {

   @Id
   private Long id;
 }
```

And you will access like this :
`select p.id from Person p`